# db_select() ignores condition() when used with join

Tags: 7, database

I want to select all rows from 'ha' table, which access column are >= 0 and node type of that nid is equal $this->ctype.

```
  protected function queryAlter() {

    if(isset($this->ctype)) {

        $this->query->leftJoin('node', 'n', 'n.nid = ha.nid');
        $this->query->conditions(
                db_and()
                ->condition('ha.access', 0, '>=')
                ->condition('n.type', $this->ctype));
        //dpr($this->query);
    }
    else {
        $this->query->condition('ha.access', 0, '>=');
    }
  }
```

$this->ctype is set and equal to 'ad'. And I have not any nodes with that type.
But db_select() ignores condition('n.type', $this->ctype) and returns all rows from ha (which NID's are not ad type).

Why this happens? And how to debug db_select() in general?

Comment: What is the class of `$this`? There is something wrong in the code you are showing, but to reply to your question I need to know which class implements those methods.

Comment: This is SiteActivity which extends HeartbeatStream. Class is in Heartbeat module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HearthbeatStream::$query` is an object of the class `PagerActivity` which extend the class `SelectQuery`; this is evident from the code for [HeartbeatStream::createQuery()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--heartbeat--includes--heartbeatstream.inc/function/HeartbeatStream%3a%3acreateQuery/7), where the value of the property is initialized with the following line.

```
$this->query = db_select('heartbeat_activity', 'ha')->extend('PagerActivity');
```

The fact `PagerActivity` is an extender of `SelectQuery` means that every method implemented by `SelectQuery` is also implemented from `PagerActivity`.

[SelectQuery::conditions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aconditions/7) is a getter method, not a setter method. The only method to set the condition associated with a `SelectQuery` object is [SelectQuery::condition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3acondition/7).

The code should be re-written as:

```
  protected function queryAlter() {
    if (isset($this->ctype)) {
      $this->query->leftJoin('node', 'n', 'n.nid = ha.nid');
      $this->query->condition(('ha.access', 0, '>=')
        ->condition('n.type', $this->ctype));
    }
    else {
        $this->query->condition('ha.access', 0, '>=');
    }
  }
```

To make a comparison, this is the code executed from [blog_page_user()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--blog--blog.pages.inc/function/blog_page_user/7):

```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $nids = $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'sticky', 'created'))
    ->condition('type', 'blog')
    ->condition('uid', $account->uid)
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('sticky', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->limit(variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10))
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();
```

There are some similarities with your code:

- in both the cases, the value returned from `db_select()` is passed to the `extend()` method
- in both the cases, more than one condition is applied

Using the value returned from `db_and()` with `SelectQuery::condition()` is not necessary, as the constructor of `SelectQuery` initializes the value of `SelectQuery::$where` (used by [SelectQuery::condition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3acondition/7)) with the following code:

```
  $this->where = new DatabaseCondition('AND');
```

The returned value is the same returned by [db_and()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_and/7).

```
function db_and() {
  return new DatabaseCondition('AND');
}
```